# RegEx match anything except linebreaks up to positive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match certain text lines up to a specific string in RegEx (PCRE). Here's an example:

```
000000
999999900

20.10.19

Amoxicillin 1000 Heumann 20 Filmtbl. N2 - PZN: 04472730

-

Dr. Max Mustermann
```

In this text, I'd like to match exactly this part:

```
Amoxicillin 1000 Heumann 20 Filmtbl. N2
```

The similarity is always the part with the PZN and a 7-8 digit number behind that at the end of every line I'd like to match. However, the PZN part might sometimes be in the next line instead of directly behind it:

```
000000
999999900

20.10.19

Amoxicillin 1000 Heumann 20 Filmtbl. N2
 - PZN: 04472730

-

Dr. Max Mustermann
```

So it's either directly behind it or in the next line. I've tried to do so using this RegEx:

```
.*(?=[ \-\r\n]+PZN)
```

This does work, however, in the first example above, it matches this:

```
Amoxicillin 1000 Heumann 20 Filmtbl. N2 -
```

Notice the " -" at the end. This should not be included in the match. I suppose RegEx prioritizes the `.*` part since it's working from left to right, and therefore only strips the very last character of the lookahead. I can't wrap my head around as to how to do it otherwise though.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`^.*\S(?=\s*-\s*PZN:\s*\d{7,8})`](https://regex101.com/r/FDPucD/3)?

Comment: try [`.*\s*(?=\s*-[ \r\n]+PZN)`](https://regex101.com/r/qYWHau/1/)

Comment: Or try a capturing group `^(?![^\S\r\n]*$)(.+)\s* - PZN: \d{7,8}$` See https://regex101.com/r/niOnv7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a capturing group and match 0+ whitespace chars before the `- PZN:` part.

```
^(?![^\S\r\n]*$)(.+)\s* - PZN: \d{7,8}$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `(?![^\S\r\n]*$)` Assert not an empty line
- `(.+)\s*` Capture in group 1 matching any char 1+ times followed by 0+ times a whitespace char
- `- PZN:`  Match a space `-` and space followed by `PZN:` and space
- `\d{7,8}` Match 7-8 digits
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsEH9Q/1/)

Another option is the same pattern in the form of using a lookahead

```
^(?![^\S\r\n]*$).+(?=\s* - PZN: \d{7,8}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFH1Ur/1)

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
^(.+?)(?=\s?- PZN:)
```

- `^(.+?)` - at the start of a line lazily match everything
- `(?=\s?- PZN:)` - tell `.+?` to quit matching once we detect an upcoming `PZN:`

https://regex101.com/r/dhpth0/1/